# No tt_news archive after upgrade

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I use the tt_news extension in TYPO3. I have updated the extension from 2.5 to 3.2.1. After the update, my pages which were using `AMENU` and `###TEMPLATE_ARCHIVE###` are not working.

This is error I get in the FE:
[image]

My content folder for archived items is well configured (http://clip2net.com/s/28oYA), as well as TS constant:

```
plugin.tt_news.archiveTypoLink.parameter = 104
```

What might be wrong here?

Comment: AFAIK tt_news has an update wizard in extension details. Please have a look inside the EM. Other than that, are you sure that you end up on the right page (104)?

Comment: Hi - I figured out that date when news will be archived (Archive date) was not entered on any single news record in my database. People who entered news would basically skip it because there was default (month or so after publishing news). However this defaults don't exist in v3.2.1 so my archive list won't pick up any news. Is there any way to configure this, or should I write SQL UPDATE statement on all of my records to set archive date one month after news is published?

Comment: fix all empty ones with an sql statement and use `TCAdefaults.tt_news.archivedate = timestamp` to set a default value. Unfortunally you can not use something like `+1 week`. You will need to write a little helper extension that can be used to set a default value on the fly. Or you can just change the `TCA` to `required`.

Comment: I have updated my records using this SQL query in case someone else needs to do the same: 

UPDATE tt_news n SET archivedate = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.datetime), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) WHERE n.uid<=50000;

I will check options with TCA for sure to force news editors to enter archive date from now on as I am too lazy to code TS for this.